# Warhammer Fantasy Dual Wield Ruling

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

If you have any unit that was more than one attack and the unit is dual wielding how many attacks does he have?

I.e. if a unit has 3 attacks but is dual wielding, does he in turn have 4 attacks or does he get a total of 6 attacks as a result of 3 attacks with the dual wield?

Comment: Can you add the text of the dual wielding rule? It’s been about 10 years since I've played, but IIRC it’s +1 attack, not double attacks.

Answer (score 1):

So 'dual wielding' isn't a term that's used in Warhammer Fantasy's rules. But models frequently have more than one weapon.  As a general rule however, this is more for the ability to choose the right tool for the right job, as opposed to using multiple weapons at the same time.

There are two times when a character will use two different weapons at once:
1) Brace of pistols: Some characters have the option of taking multiple pistols.  They're stat block will explain exactly how they work, since 'repeater pistols' work slightly differently than 'repeater handbows' which are again slightly different from someone who is just covered in flintlock pistols.

2) Models with extra hand weapons can use them in combat for an extra attack.  There are a whole bunch of times where this doesn't work, but basically as long as the model is on foot, and not using any special weapons, or magical weapons, then an extra hand weapon will grant 1 extra attack.

If a model has multiple different kinds of weapons, the general rule is that you choose which one he is using at the start of the round.

Answer (score 0):

If u ask about Warhammer fantasy battle, 2 hand weapons or additional hand weapon gives the unit extra attack. So unit with 3A and 2 hand weapons have 4 attacks.